# Electrons in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

If Electrons in quantum field theory are an expanded field. They have infinite lengths. How does electron transfer in an electrical or chemical process, how does the principle of the exclusion of Paul's work, which says that fermions can not occupy the same place?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4616.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange!  Your question is too vague or too broad to be easily addressed in a forum like this.  Can you narrow your question, or provide some context for the question?

Comment: The Pauli exclusion principle applies to bound states. Are you familiar with how bound states are treated in QFT?

Comment: No.I just want to know how materials exchange electrons if they are spatially expanded

Comment: What do you mean by "spatially expanded"?

Comment: quanta: highly unified spatially extended bundles of field energy. https://blog.oup.com/2017/02/quantum-fields/

Comment: "Spatially extended," rather than "spatially expanded," makes a lot more sense here. Pauli exclusion prohibits electrons from occupying the exact same _state_ (in other words, having the exact same _extended spatial distribution_ and other quantum numbers).

Comment: Well then, how can these quanta (electrons) move from one material to another?